# Test of independence for categorical and discrete variables

Tags: categorical-data, independence

First time writing question on stack. Mostly, I could find the answer needed from previous questions. This time couldn't find such a. Lets say I have categorical variable y(dependent) which can have values of 0(no occurrence) and 1(occurrence). And x, where rows are frequencies of how many times value is higher than mean. What test would be better to test dependence?

Comment: So is X a binary categorical variable?

Comment: Yes. For example, x = 2 ,3,5,1,0. y = 1,0,1,0,0. I don't know how to copy tables here.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193715/exploring-the-relationships-between-discrete-and-categorical-data

Comment: You could try some version of logistic regression, but yor representation of x seems fishy. Use x "as is", and maybe spline it in the logistic regression.